# paintComponent don't work. I can't find the reason

Tags: java, paintcomponent

I know, this is a very basic question but I have no idea why my `paintComponent` does nothing.
Its main functionality should be to draw an image but it does not even draw a rect or circle.
So please help me -.-

Class with `JFrame`:

```
public class JuliaView extends JFrame implements Observer{

//:::: ACTIONS
public final String ACTION_ENDE = "Ende";
public final String ACTION_PAINT = "Paint";
public final String ACTION_COMPLEX = "+a.x+b.x";
public final String ACTION_LINK = "Link";
public final String ACTION_CLEAR = "Clear";
//:::: Components
//private JFrame frame;
private Image image;
private JButton btEnde;
private JButton btPaint;
private JButton btClear;
private JPanel content;
public JuliaPanel drawArea;     //Bereich für Paint
//private JButton btAutoPaint;
private JTextField tfComplex;
private JTextField tfLink;
//:::: Observer
private JuliaModel model;
private JuliaController controller;



public JuliaView(String titel,JuliaModel model){
    //frame = new JFrame(titel);
    super(titel);
    this.model = model;
    image = null;
    drawArea = new JuliaPanel(model);
    content = new JPanel();
}

public void makeView() {    //Zur Zeit ausser Funktion
    // Fenster
    addWindowListener( controller);   

    initForm();
    resetView();
}

/**
 * Anordnen der Komponenten im GridBag
 */
public void initForm(){
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());;
    this.setBounds(200, 200, 800, 600);
    content.setBounds(0, 0, 200, 600);
    content.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    content.setLayout(new BoxLayout(content, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
    drawArea.setOpaque(true);
    //content.add(tfComplex,BorderLayout.CENTER)
    this.getContentPane().add(content,BorderLayout.WEST);
    this.getContentPane().add(drawArea,BorderLayout.CENTER);

    //left outs adding to content witch works fine


    setVisible( true);
    pack();
    drawArea.testImage();       //Should fill the image
    image = drawArea.getImage();
    drawArea.paintComponents(getGraphics());    //Paint the image
    //this.paintComponents(getGraphics());

}}
```

Class witch holds the JPanel to draw on:

```
public class JuliaPanel extends JPanel {
public final int darstellungsBreite = 600;
public final int darstellungsHoehe = 600;
private JuliaModel model;
private BufferedImage image;

public JuliaPanel(JuliaModel model){
    super();
    this.setOpaque(true);
    this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    image = null;
    this.model = model;
    image = new BufferedImage(darstellungsBreite, darstellungsHoehe,  BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(darstellungsBreite,darstellungsHoehe));
}
public JuliaPanel(){
    super();
    image = null;

    image = new BufferedImage(darstellungsBreite, darstellungsHoehe, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(darstellungsBreite,darstellungsHoehe));
}
private Color createColor(int in)       //in[0,255]
{
    float rgb = (float)in/256;          //in[0.0,1.0]
    if(rgb<=0.5){
        Color c = new Color(rgb,(float) (rgb*1.5),rgb*2);   //mal schauen was da bei rauskommt
        return c;           
    }
    else{
        Color c = new Color(rgb,rgb,rgb);
        return c;
    }
}
public void testImage(){
    System.out.println("Methode suc. called");
    image.createGraphics().setColor(Color.BLACK);
    image.createGraphics().fillRect(300, 300, 100, 100);
    if(image == null){System.out.println("Image is null");}

}
public void createImage(){

    for(int j=0;j<darstellungsBreite;j++)
        for(int i=0;i<darstellungsHoehe;i++)
        {
            image.createGraphics().setColor(createColor(model.getFarbwert(j, i)));
            image.createGraphics().drawRect(j, i, 1, 1);
            image.createGraphics().fillRect(j, i, 1, 1);
        }
}
public void clearImage(){
    image.createGraphics().setColor(Color.WHITE );
    image.createGraphics().clearRect(getX(), getY(), darstellungsBreite, darstellungsHoehe);
}
public BufferedImage getImage(){return image;}
public void paintComponents(Graphics g)
{

    super.paintComponents(g);
    //g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    //g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

    Graphics2D g2d =  (Graphics2D)g.create();
    g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g2d.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
    g2d.drawImage(image,0,0,this);
    g2d.dispose();
}
```

I already tried to take the `paintComponent` method in the other class, but that changed nothing.

Comment: Override `paintComponent` not `paintComponents` & don't call it explicitly, let Swing do that

Comment: okay, i did it and now its paint :) buut when u look at the testImage() methode in my Panel Class. the rect is at the right position and it is white not in any other color i type in